# Converting a entire python project to exe

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

So I've made a project which takes a photo of your face or you can use any image and let it be fed into a neural network trained to classify celebrities. With that, you can figure out what celeb you look like.

Here is the [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLlnnqRcJXw) and [GitHub](https://github.com/5Volts/Celebrities) link.

I wanted to convert it to exe so that it's easier for people to download and use it but so far I've tried cx_freeze, pyinstaller and none of them work. I can't use py2exe because I'm on python 3.5.

I was able to convert live_detect.py(which is the main python script that runs the program) to an exe with pyinstaller but when I run it I got the following error.[image: img of error]

I think a lot of the python to exe converter would have trouble converting a project this size. Other than modules, there are a lot of different items needed in different directory for the neural network model and so on. Was wondering if any of you had any suggestion.

Comment: I'm also having big projects (150MB+ with libraries) and for me pyinstaller works the best. So far i didn't have any issues. The only thing, that you really have to be careful is to have proper python file structure with relative paths... Then i don't see any problems.

Comment: Have you tried cython? It may be able to compile your python code. You can also embed a python interpreter into cythons object files. Than you just compile/link like a c/c++ file.

Comment: Please include the error as a text-block instead of using a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called `auto-py-to-exe` which creates an exe out of your program without requiring you to create a setup file. The interface is great and allows you to easily create and exe without creating a setup.py. This also allows you to package your app as a single exe, without any other files. Below is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

You can install the program by typing into the command line:

`python -m pip install auto-py-to-exe`

You can run it by typing in:

`auto-py-to-exe`

To see more about auto-py-to-exe, please visit the PyPI page at https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/.